# Which scikit-learn tools can handle multivariate output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been fiddling with different scikit-learn tools.  The supervised-learning classes all have the same general API where you call `model.fit(X, y)` to fit the model.  With some of these (at least ExtraTreesRegressor), I can pass in a 2-dimensional array for `y` and it works fine.  With others, it doesn't work.  It doesn't usually say *why* it doesn't work, though: I get shape mismatch errors that suggest that it can only predict a single output dimension without actually saying so.  E.g., for stochastic gradient descent:

```
>>> X.shape
(77946, 24)
>>> y.shape
(77946, 24)
>>> mach = sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor()
>>> mach.fit(X, y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    mach.fit(X, y)
  File "C:\FakeProgs\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 842, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "C:\FakeProgs\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 811, in _fit
    coef_init, intercept_init)
  File "C:\FakeProgs\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 752, in _partial_fit
    _check_fit_data(X, y)
  File "C:\FakeProgs\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 228, in _check_fit_data
    raise ValueError("Shapes of X and y do not match.")
ValueError: Shapes of X and y do not match.
```

Well, yes they do match.  It works if I use just one column of `y`, but I don't know if this means multivariate `y` isn't supported, or I'm just not doing it right.

Is there explicit documentation saying which scikit classes can accept a 2-dimensional `y` and which cannot?  How can I tell if a given kind of model supports this, without just trying to guess from the error messages?

Answer (score 4):

The [fit method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.fit) of `SGDRegressor` explicitly states that the expected target has shape `(n_samples,)` hence 1D.

You can wrap a for loop to fit one `SGDRegressor` per-target if you need. Otherwise you can try `Ridge`, `RidgeCV`, `ElasticNet` or `ElasticNetCV`.

*Edit:* also if you would like to add support for multi-target to `SGDRegressor` please feel free to send a pull-request.