# Scikit-Learn Multiple Regression Fails with ElasticNetCV

Tags: scikit-learn

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV.html) and [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650115/which-scikit-learn-tools-can-handle-multivariate-output), `ElasticNetCV` accepts multiple output regression.  When I try it, though, it fails.  Code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd

nsubj = 10
nfeat_train = 5
nfeat_predict = 20
x = rnd.random((nsubj, nfeat_train))
y = rnd.random((nsubj, nfeat_predict))
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x,y) # works
el = linear_model.ElasticNetCV()
el.fit(x,y) # fails
```

Error message:

```
ValueError:  Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

This is with scikit-learn version 0.14.1.  Is this a mismatch between the documentation and implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at `sklearn.linear_model.MultiTaskElasticNetCV`. But beware, this object assumes that your multiple targets share features. Thus, a feature is either active for all tasks (with variable activation for each, which can be small), or active for none of them. Before using this object, make sure this is the functionality you need.

Comment: This isn't the functionality I need, but if it's the only way to get multiple regression output, I may have to use it.  It looks to me like the failure of `ElasticNetCV` to support multiple outputs is a bug in scikit-learn.  I know that they have been working on multiple regression outputs, but they may not have gotten to `ElasticNetCV` yet.

Comment: It is not a bug. Multiple targets is a nice to have feature, but it needs to be implemented. Since treating multiple independent targets together yields no mathematical optimization gain, the multi-target has to be beneficial on the implementation side, and significantly beat a loop over targets. This is possible, so pull requests welcome :)

Comment: I guess it's more a bug in the documentation than in the implementation, as the documentation clearly says that it is supported: "y : narray, shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_targets)".  The only advantage is in removing the Python-level loop (which does save a lot of time in other regressors), even though mathematically multiple outputs and looping over the regressor are equivalent.